# How to make GUI Buttons on GUI Texture resolution independent in Unity3d?

Tags: android, button, user-interface, screen-resolution

I am newbie to Unity3d and Android developent, and I am in need of your help to make my GUI controls resolution independent.

I have a GUI Texture in my scene to be used as a graphical background for a controller (see image 1):

[image]

Above this, a set of GUI buttons is rendered in absolute x,y screen positions (see image 2):

[image]

Those two elements rendered together makes the buttons controller for my android application, in a 480x320 HVGA Landscape screen resolution (see image 3):

[image]

The problem is that if the resolution is changed to 800x480 WVGA Landscape, everything is meshed up as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image]

I have tryed to make use of the Matrix4x4 to keep the GUI buttons scaled to a new resolution, but I still get them scattered all around screen.

**Could anyone be kind enough to give some advise or maybe a code snippet on how to make both GUI buttons on absolute possitions and GUI Texture, screen resolution independent?**

Thank you all in advance for your answers.